# Triggering events from View to ViewModel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

working in WPF with C# I am generating an event from a view MyView and what I need to do is to handle it in the associated view model class MyViewModel.

I am using caliburn.micro to solve and this is the code in synthesis:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyView"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             DataContext="MyViewModelInstance"
             cal:Message.Attach="[Event CancelEvent]=[Action CancelButton_Click_MyViewModelHandler($source,$eventArgs)]">
                <Grid> 
                  <Button Click="CancelButton_Click"> </Button>
                </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind I handle the click event generating a CancelEvent:

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
   public event EventHandler CancelEvent;
   private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     if(CancelEvent!=null)
     {
         CancelEvent(sender,e);
     }
   }
}
```

In the class MyViewModel I defined the function

```
 public void MyViewMOdelHandler(Object sender, EventArgs arg)
```

What I need to do is to handle the CancelEvent in MyViewModelInstance, using the code above results as no one is subscribed to the CancelEvent (CancelEvent == null) so that the CancelEvent handler in MyViewModelInstance is not invoked.

Does anybody know a solution to the problem? (caliburn is not mandatory)

Thanks in advance.

-Z-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is easy. In your view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyView"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         DataContext="YourViewModel"

            <Grid> 
              <Button Click="CancelButton_Click" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action MyViewModelHandler($source,$eventArgs)]">> </Button>
            </Grid>
```

CancelButton_Click in code behind can be removed.
In your viewmodel:

```
public class YourViewModel : PropertyChangedBase 
{
    public void MyViewModelHandler(Object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer perfectly solved my problem. Furthermore I found a usefull reference which solved in different ways the same issue, this is this is the link http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you're not directly attaching the click event of the button? as that would be the simplest solution.

Looking at your example it would seem the Message.Attach is specifiing a method that doesn't exist.

If the method on the view model is

```
public void MyViewModelHandler(Object sender, EventArgs arg)
```

then the attach syntax would be

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event CancelEvent]=[Action MyViewModelHandler($source,$eventArgs)]"
```

Comment: No reason, attaching the event directly to the button click is the right answer to my problem as explained also from user2250152 in his response. Thanks for your time